# Using the MongoDB .Net Driver to both Group Data and bring back other Document Data

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb, aggregation

From this collection, I'd like to return the data grouped by grade that also contains a list of names:

```
{_id: ..., name: "amy", grade: "A"}
{_id: ..., name: "bob", grade: "D"}
{_id: ..., name: "cathy", grade: "B"}
{_id: ..., name: "doug", grade: "A"}
{_id: ..., name: "edith", grade: "C"}
{_id: ..., name: "frank", grade: "C"}
```

Example return data:

```
{grade: "A", names: ["amy", "doug"], count: 2}
{grade: "B", names: ["cathy"], count: 1}
{grade: "C", names: ["edith", "frank"], count: 2}
{grade: "D", names: ["bob"], count: 1}
```

Basically, I want to do this (but with the MongoDB .Net driver):

```
db.collection.aggregate(
   { $group: { 
    _id: { grade: "$grade"}, 
    names: { "$addToSet": "$name" }, 
    count: { "$sum": 1 } 
    }})
```

I tried this, but $addToSet is not an aggregate operation:

```
var group = new BsonDocument
    {
        { "$group",
            new BsonDocument
                {
                    { "_id", new BsonDocument
                                 {
                                     {
                                        "grade","$grade"
                                     }
                                 }
                    },
                    { "count", new BsonDocument
                                     {
                                         {
                                             "$sum", 1
                                         }
                                     }
                    },
                    { "$addToSet", new BsonDocument 
                        {
                            {"names", "$name"},
                        }
                    }
                }
        }
    };
    var pipeline = new[] { group };
    col
       .Aggregate<BsonDocument>(pipeline)
       .ForEachAsync(doc =>
               {
                   // do stuff
               });
       );
```

I'm using MongoDB v4.0 with the .Net Driver v2.13

Answer (score 0):

Syntax was a little off above for `$addToSet`. Here's how to do it...

```
var group = new BsonDocument
    {
        { "$group",
            new BsonDocument
                {
                    { "_id", new BsonDocument
                                 {
                                     {
                                        "grade","$grade"
                                     }
                                 }
                    },
                    { "count", new BsonDocument
                                     {
                                         {
                                             "$sum", 1
                                         }
                                     }
                    },
                    { "names", new BsonDocument
                                    {
                                        {"$addToSet", "$name"},

                                    }
                    }
             }
        }
    };
    var pipeline = new[] { group };
    col
       .Aggregate<BsonDocument>(pipeline)
       .ForEachAsync(doc =>
               {
                   // do stuff
               });
       );
```